# Setup UIScrollView for Autolayout in order to scroll _only_ for small screens

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, autolayout, screen

I have an iPhone only app in portrait orientation that's bound to run on the iPhone 4s and upwards. The design is aimed at the iPhone 6.

I'd like have it work in such a way that for small screens the content scrolls vertically if it doesn't fit. Everything is laid out using Autolayout and looks perfect on the iPhone 6 and up. But on the smaller iPhones it tries to squeeze the content vertically and breaks the design.

I have already embedded everything inside a content view and added this view to the UIScrollView.
I thought if I'd add a height constraint to the content view, the UIView had it's *contentSize* and would scroll - but it doesn't. Autolayout breaks this constraint.

I thought I'd understand the "special" constraints for scrollviews with autolayout...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints should be like,

scrollview - top,bottom,leading,trailing

view (content view) - top,bottom,leading,trailing,fix height and horizontally center in container

and add your all other stuff in that view. you will got desired result. it will scroll in small screen size then content view and will not scroll for bigger screen then content view.

After this setup if you unable to scroll then check `content view's bottom constraint's constant` in `size inspector`. make it zero (if unable to scroll then only).

there are many tutorials available if you want to know more deeply as links given in other answers

Hope this will help :)